# Google App Engine datastore: filter()

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to retrieve an entry from Google App Engine's datastore using the `filter()` method as follows:

```
result = Sender.all().filter("email =", email).filter("source_address =", source).filter("dest_address =", dest).filter("food_type =", food_type)
```

Then, if such an entry exists, I change the value of one of the columns in that entry. Otherwise, I'm displaying an error message.

```
        if result:
            for e in result:
                e.time_of_delivery = toj
                e.put()
                self.response.write("Time of delivery successfully rescheduled !")
        else:
            self.response.write("No such request.")
```

However, even when an entry in the datastore doesn't exist based on the conditions imposed by the `filter()` methods that I have used, the `No such request.` message is never displayed. Instead, all I get is a blank page.

What exactly is wrong with my code? Why is the `else` part of my code never executed when an entry is not found in the datastore, i.e when `result = None` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`object.__nonzero__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__):

> Called to implement truth value testing and the built-in operation `bool()`; should return False or True, or their integer equivalents 0 or 1. When this method is not defined, `__len__()` is called, if it is defined, and the object is considered true if its result is nonzero. If a class defines neither `__len__()` nor `__nonzero__()`, all its instances are considered true.

It seems that the gae `Query` does not implement either `__nonzero__` or `__len__` so a better way to check is:

```
if result.count(limit=1):  # retrieves only 1 record
    # results exist
else:
    # results don't exist
```

Comment: This is pretty inefficient - calling .count() is essentially the same cost as doing the query.

Comment: Very inefficient in fact, as the query will be fore performed twice.

Comment: It's not "very" or "totally" inefficient unless the result set is big enough to make a noticeable impact. I've updated the code to make it efficient enough

Comment: We don't know how big the result set is.  but why do it at all.  Just work with results if there are none do something els.e

Comment: @TimHoffman the `count()` method is faster than `get()` or `fetch()` since it doesn't retrieve all fields in documents but merely a count. It still gets slower as the result set increases but that was not the OP's question at all. I believe adding `limit=1` should be more than enough in terms of efficiency

Comment: Except that if you are going to process each entity anyway - as per the question code, then you are doing a completely redundant query.

Comment: Redundant, True, but it's certainly not at all "totally" or "very" inefficient. In all cases, you have already provided a different approach in your answer so it's up to people's preferences to decide (so long as the real problem has been addressed) :)

Answer (score 2):

The query object will always resolve to true as per the answer earlier..

The query is not performed until you count, iterate, fetch or get on it's result set.

I would do something more like

```
   has_result = False
   for e in results:
       e.time_of_delivery = toj
       e.put()
       self.response.write("Time of delivery successfully rescheduled !")
       has_result = True
   if not has_result:
       self.response.write("No such request.")
```

Answer (score -1):

What do the logs from the App Engine Development server say? Your request looks like an old-style datastore request, not an ndb one, so you may have the wrong syntax and the code is throwing an exception before any response is sent.